# Kubernetes creating a deployment but it's never available

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have a .yaml file which creates a deployment and service for nginx image.
Creating both runs fine however when I check the deployment status I get this:

```
NAME       DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
frontend   1         1         1            0           8m
```

Available is always at 0. Below is my .yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: website
    tier: frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: website
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: killabien/nginx
          name: nginx
```

Website selector is pointing to another deployment.
I thought that maybe my image is corrupted and changed it to standard nginx:alpine but the result was the same.
Why is the deployment not created?

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `kubectl describe deployment frontend`?

Comment: Okay, I found the problem. It keeps crashing because of a mistake in my nginx conf file. I will fix it now, thank you for your reply and sorry for asking a trivial question. Cheers.

Comment: @davidb Please answer your own question and close it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turned out that my nginx configuration file was incorrect.
I had to change it and it's running fine now.